# Nativescript xml template not refreshing cache issue

Tags: android, xml, caching, nativescript

so I ran into the following issue.

Sometimes when changing an XML template and getting an error for one reason or another (running the livesync with genymotion), even removing the file content entirely would not reset the file on compilation.

my package.json:

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.myapp",
    "tns-android": {
        "version": "1.7.1"
    }
},
"dependencies": {
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "1.7.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
}
```

Example:

file.xml

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
  class="my-page">
      <WrapLayout horizontalAlignment="center">
          <Button text="NEW ACCOUNT" tap="onTapAction" visibility="{{ noAccounts ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
      </WrapLayout>
</Page>
```

For some reason, after adding the Button tag, I got an error showing up.
Then I tried to:

- rollback
- remove all cache `rm -Rf ./platforms/android/build/* && rm -Rf ./platforms/android/.gradle/ && tns prepare android && tns build android`
- delete most folders and do a new `tns install`
- `tns platform remove android` > `tns platform add android`
- etc...

Nothing works and I always get the same error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.myapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/pages/login/start.xml:54:7
 ���close tagname
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/ui/builder/builder.js, line: 157, column: 16

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/ui/builder/builder.js', line: 157, column: 17
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/xml/xml.js', line: 176, column: 17
    Frame: function:'EasySAXParser.parse', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/js-libs/easysax/easysax.js', line: 605, column: 22
    Frame: function:'XmlParser.parse', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/xml/xml.js', line: 194, column: 22
```

Comment: As a side information, I just managed to somehow "trick" the compiler. What I did is change the following in **package.json**: `"nativescript": {
 "id": "org.nativescript.myapp2" ... Basically, adding "2" at the end of the ID. This is dirty as hell, so I am still waiting for a proper answer. Thank you

Comment: Is app/pages/login/start.xml logged in the error the same xml page you are showing

Comment: Yes it is, that's the page where the problem showed up first.
Another thing I noticed is that if I want to see changes from files in "App_Ressources/Android/values/colors.xml", I have to do the same trick to show the changes (rename the app id).

Comment: You should check out NativeScript-liveedit plugin. If you don't like these current limitations. It's a little beefier way of testing android apps right now. If I'm not using liveedit plugin and have this issue I have to restart livesync or the run command to fix it.

Comment: I read about liveedit, but the problem that I encounter is different as it's a compilation issue (and I believe Gradle is involved). Basically, just forgetting to close a tag (wrong copy/paste or other) is enough to break everything and usually I would need to re-install the whole thing and update the package.json version to kill the cache for sure. I wonder if NativeScript 2.0 still has the issue. Not had the chance to try it out yet.